# Running into a memory exception on a for loop statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a following out of memory exception when I'm looping through a variable. My solution would be if this variable count is great than 100 only process my for loop as a batch of 100.. I'm just not sure how to do this. Any input?

```
     var statementResults = GetCustomerDetailsForPrinting(searchCriteria.CustomerNumbers);

     if statementResults.Count() > 100 then process in batch....

     for (int i = 0; i < statementResults.Count(); i++)
     {

     }
```

Comment: Do you mean only process the first 100 only or process all of them in batches of 100?

Comment: It would appear that statementResults is being modified during the execution of your loop and as a result the Count constantly increases. Alternatively, if there are millions, perhaps the system is just being overloaded during iteration.

Comment: Either way, we need to see what the internal working of the for loop are in order to help.

Comment: We need a [mre] to understand what is happening.

Comment: Your life will become so much easier if you [learn how to use the built-in debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 2):

It's not the loop that generates the out of memory exception. It's because the statementResults is an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` and is 'executed' when iterated. For example calling a `Count()`

Everytime you execute the `Count()` method, the whole query is executed (again)

Don't use a `for(int i=0;...)`

Do like this:

```
var statementResults = GetCustomerDetailsForPrinting(searchCriteria.CustomerNumbers);

foreach(var statementResult in statementResults)
{
    // handle items.
}
```

This is how you stream the results. And if you only want to process 100 items. use:

```
var statementResults = GetCustomerDetailsForPrinting(searchCriteria.CustomerNumbers);

foreach(var statementResult in statementResults.Take(100))
{
    // handle items.
}
```

You can also put the `Take(100)` behind the `GetCustomerDetailsForPrinter()` etc.

Comment: If you are wedded to a traditional `for` loop, pull the `Count()` call out of the loop (`var count = statementResults.Count(); for int i = 0; i < count(); ++i)`).

Comment: How would you access one item with a traditional loop? You can't access an `IEnumerable<T>`/`IQueryable<T>` by index without persisting. The only thing that can be used with a traditional loop is persisting them to a list or array. Like: `GetCustomerDetailsForPrinting(searchCriteria.CustomerNumbers).ToList()` But that will give an out of memory exception.. `GetCustomerDetailsForPrinting(searchCriteria.CustomerNumbers).Take(100).ToList()` will probably work but not scalable.

Comment: True, I was addressing *"Everytime you execute the Count() method, the whole query is executed (again)*".  Yours is the better solution (hence, no answer on my part).  I was pointing out that pulling a function call out of a loop is usually a good thing to do